# Notation of density functions

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, notation, density-function

Assume two jointly normally distributed variables X,Y.

Then what I often see is that densities are written as follows:

$f_X(x)$ as the density of X, $f_Y(y)$ as the density of Y, $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ as the joint density, $f_{X|Y}(x|y)$ as the conditional density, and so on.

My question: Why do people include this subindex? What is the meaning behind it? Does it add any information? E.g. why don't you just write $f(x)$ or $f(X)$ instead of $f_X(x)$? Does something like $f_Y(x)$ even make sense?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: To simply keep track of the random variable whose density is being considered. You pretty much answered this yourself by merely listing all the ways it can be used.

Comment: Of course the index can be left out. It is only there to make things more easy and to decrease the chance that our alphabet is not large enough. If you dislike them then feel free to do it without these indices, but do keep them properly apart of course. "Does something like $f_Y(x)$ even make sense?..." Well, can you give me any reason for doubting that? Btw, if $X$ is a random variable then also $f(X)$ is a random variable, and PDF's are not random variables.

Comment: Of course $f_Y(y)$ makes sense, but $f_Y(x)$?

Comment: I made a typo (and repaired) in former comment. Again: what is your reason to doubt that $f_Y(x)$ makes sense? Personally I would not write the arguments if that is not necessary but would just do it with $f_X$ and $f_Y$. Further something like $\int yf_Y(y)dy$ is exactly the same as $\int xf_Y(x)dx$. Both denote the expectation of $Y$.

Comment: That helped, think I got it know. Thanks a lot!